# Does it matter which character disarms a trap?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

When disarming traps, I usually use the most rogue-like member of the party- typically my Grave Robber or Bounty Hunter. It seems to work more often but this might just be confirmation bias.

I can't find any visible stat which would affect this. Aside from changing which character risks getting hit, does using a different character to disarm a trap increase the chance of success?

Comment: Not sure if it actually helps with disarming, but I know characters have a Trap Resist stat, so I always end up sending whoever in my party has the highest Trap Resist, in the theory that it either helps disarm or helps protect me if I flub it. No idea if it actually matters for disarms vs accidentally walking over it, though.

Comment: @Sterno Where is trap resist displayed? I haven't seen it.

Comment: If you look at the large (wide) character sheet, et while in the village, there's a Resistances section on the right. That's where Trap Resist is. It's dependent on character class, resist level, and also on any trinkets you've got.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When looking through your party's stats you can see their trap stat. The higher the trap stat the better the chance of a successful disarm.

Comment: Also, whoever successfully disarms a trap loses some Stress. This can be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know for past builds of the game, but currently when you are near a trap a small icon resembling a web will appear near each character's energy bars, at the bottom of the screen: if you hover your mouse there, it will give you the chance to disarm the trap.

An then, apart from that, you'll find the same information in the character stat sheet, in the lower right part of it